# React: Get height of element, and this.ref has empty current

Tags: css, reactjs, ref

How can I get the height of a div inside my component? I have the following code:

```
constructor(...) {
  ...
  this.detailsRef = React.createRef();
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>A title</span>
      <div ref={this.detailsRef}>Some details</div>
    </div>
  );
 }
```

I have read that you can get the element's height by doing this:

```
this.detailsRef.current.clientHeight
```

or

```
this.detailsRef.clientHeight
```

However, that does not work for me. Do anyone have any suggestions?

**Answer**

Ok, the reason for why I did not get the height from `this.detailsRef.current.client` was because my `div` with the `ref`attached to it was a div created by `styled-components`. So when I changed my styled-component div to an ordinary div, it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.headerRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.headerRef.current.clientHeight);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 ref={this.headerRef}>Grab this element</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked now when I replaced my styled-component div to an ordinary div. I did not mention that in my original question, my bad. And thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: No worries... Notice the `console.log` is in `componentDidMount` if I were to try to access it in `render` it would be `null` @ReidunMarie